# How to remove the breadcrumbs and branding in django template?

Tags: django, jquery-selectors, django-admin, django-templates

I am able to override the breadcrumbs with django power. Now I want to remove the breadcrumbs thoroughly without any identification, since I used jQuery to remove the breadcrumbs and branding like

```
  $('.breadcrumbs').remove() 
  $('#branding').remove()
```

But still whenever I load a page the branding and breadcrumbs are also loading then only it was removing. Whenever I load the new content on the page it is appearing. That was captured and attached here. Could you suggest how to completely remove both?

[image: Breadcrumbs and Branding loading..]

Comment: Is this a site you are developing with Django?

Comment: Dude, please... this question is not okay. If you haven't noticed the Django template system and ways of overwriting blocks, then you're so completely new to Django and unable to help yourself that you should seriously NOT develop anything for a professional partner. People are here to help you with difficult and tricky questions, not to write your code. And no, you should not remove stuff with jquery. If you want it completely gone, you have to overwrite django.contrib.admin templates.

Comment: Gentle Men,I know to override django breadcrumbs and branding in template.My question is about to remove completely breadcrumbs,branding from django source code.If you overriding with empty blocks it means still it is hiding right? The question is to trash it complete.

Comment: Sorry, I now see that you're totally lost. I would advice you to improve your fundamental understanding and concepts of what's actually happening behind the curtains when you're requesting data from a server running Django. For instance the online and free Djangobook.com: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter01/

Comment: If you override them in the template then they DONT appear in the HTML from the server and they DONT get seen by the browser. You do know what HTML and HTTP are don't you? And how the WWW works?

Comment: People are downvoting a properly phrased question because the user is  a beginner? I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

Copy admin templates from `contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html` to your project template directory `templates/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html`. Then you can override whatever you do not need. For example:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
  {# add your branding in this block %}
{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
  {# removed #}
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE:** If you copy `admin/base.html` to your template directory and delete whole block (and not just it content) other templates can define this block but it would not be present on a page.

Comment: Here I know to override the breadcrumbs and branding.Here I am asking Is it possible to trash these from django source code? Because even if you override you will get the hidden thing.even i don't wanna that also.

Comment: If you override and erase them in template they would not be present in HTML page at all.

Comment: This doesn't work. The reason is that other template files like change_list.html will override what you have put into base_site.html and the breadcrumbs will still appear.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh yes it does. If you copy ``admin/base.html`` to your template directory and delete whole block (and not just it content) other templates can define this block but it would not be present on a page.

Comment: @bmihelac Please update your answer with the approach you described.